# How to use IsMobileDevice() in common controller in nopcommerce 4.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, nopcommerce

I want to use IsMobileDevice() in common controller. But when I use this method it showing me error i.e.

**1. An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = CommonController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Nop.Web.Controllers.CommonController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Nop.Web.Controllers.CommonController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:**

**2. Cannot resolve parameter 'Nop.Services.Helpers.UserAgentHelper userAgentHelper' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Nop.Core.Domain.Security.CaptchaSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Common.CommonSettings, Nop.Web.Factories.ICommonModelFactory, Nop.Services.Directory.ICurrencyService, Nop.Services.Logging.ICustomerActivityService, Nop.Services.Common.IGenericAttributeService, Nop.Services.Localization.ILanguageService, Nop.Services.Localization.ILocalizationService, Nop.Services.Logging.ILogger, Nop.Core.IStoreContext, Nop.Web.Framework.Themes.IThemeContext, Nop.Services.Vendors.IVendorService, Nop.Core.IWorkContext, Nop.Services.Messages.IWorkflowMessageService, Nop.Core.Domain.Localization.LocalizationSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Common.SitemapSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Common.SitemapXmlSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.StoreInformationSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Vendors.VendorSettings, 
Nop.Services.Helpers.UserAgentHelper)'.**

Here is my code line that how I use this method in common controller

```
var mobileDevice = _userAgentHelper.IsMobileDevice();
```

Here is the field

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
```

Why showing me error in runtime?

Comment: Might be you missing to declare in the constructor , can you please brief your code  and also I have reply the answer please check it

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked in nopCommerce 4.20 about IsMobileDevice method  in a common controller and its working fine, 
it will return true or false, 
I have tried with google chrome

Here is the code which I have Implement

```
private readonly IUserAgentHelper _userAgentHelper;
public CommonController(IUserAgentHelper userAgentHelper)
{
  _userAgentHelper = userAgentHelper;
}


public virtual IActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        var model = new ContactUsModel();

        var mobileDevice = _UserAgentHelper.IsMobileDevice();
        if(mobileDevice)
           return true;

        model = _commonModelFactory.PrepareContactUsModel(model, false);
        return View(model);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error shown, states that your controller is not being created because missing dependencies. Therefore, the line you're showing is not even being called at all; the error happens before that, when creating the controller.

In particular, you're expecting an instance of `UserAgentHelper`, but Autofac doesn't know how to get it. Service dependencies should be requested by their interface.

In short, you should require an `IUserAgentHelper`, not an `UserAgentHelper`.